# How do I access posts.xml from GAS?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-script, gdata, google-sites

I'm trying to UrlFetch the RSS/Atom feed from my site's news page "posts" URL https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain/my-site/my-announcements-page/posts.xml. It works in the browser for me as a logged user.

I am wanting to to do a Urlfetch because it seems to be a super fast way to get a count of pages and dates (<2 seconds). Doing it via the SitesApp Pages iteration or search takes 5 to 25 seconds). The site is a tiny one with lightweight content and < 50 pages.

Anyway, so I want to UrlFetch my site's posts URL and I guess I need an OAuth scope and get a token.

I have tried the scope "https://sites.google.com/feeds/" from the gdata Sites API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth and using it on the Oauth Playground 2.0 and it works for documented API feed urls but not for my site's posts.xml URL. I get a 401 "Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope" when I try to access that in the playground.

So my question is: Is it possible to use Urlfetch with an oauth token to access the pages's posts.xml? What OAuth scope do I use to get the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close off this question. I didn't find a way to access the pages's posts.xml via a urlfetch. Instead, I created my own ContentService function to return as text the number of the page's children published since a particular time via `myAnnouncementsPage.getChildren()`.

Answer (score 0):

UrlFetchApp currently supports only OAuth 1.0. Try using that instead.

Comment: I really doubt that is the problem. Specially because after the error, he tried it on the oAuth playground, and even there he couldn't. It probably a question of nonexistent scope for "inside" news feed.

Comment: @Corey I tried also just now on the original OAuth Playground site (which is 1.0) and got a token. Accessing from there the API feeds (get https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/mydomain PASS) (get ...posts.xml FAIL... 403, forbidden). This is the same result as with the OAuth 2.0 scenario I outlined in my question.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Yeah, if you can't hit it via the playground, it sounds like Sites doesn't expose it.